# Which American City is this?

Tags: usa, where-on-earth, identify-this

My friends and I had a discussion which American city this is. And what building this is?
We need to know the name of the city.

See this picture below
[image]

Can any one tell me which city this so me and my friends can finally go to sleep ?

Comment: It looks like museum to me..

Comment: [Cross post reference, in case it gets answered there](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?s=4840bb5761ce1d0fa36254fb9ad7f1a6&p=118714584#post118714584)

Comment: Can you give us more info? A higher-resolution image? Where did you get the image? How do you know it's from America?

Comment: The only we've got is this picture. It's a quiz on a dutch website. This picture is located in one of the big City's of the USA. We have to figure it out what City this is. We were hoping someone in the USA would reconize the building. This picture was taken on Google maps. In the picture there is a flag. We think it's the flag of the state of massachusetts.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a court house of some description. Thought for a bit it was the [US Supreme court](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@38.8909375,-77.0035206,3a,75y,197.03h,97.1t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sndqKL50NFQFj-uSoQCoOXg!2e0) but it's not quite right

Comment: ARGH. Was so sure with the [New York Court of Appeals building in Albany](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@42.6521001,-73.7546266,3a,75y,55.06h,100.63t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sZXZfvm9ie6cZXW-Ih_6R1A!2e0!6m1!1e1) but it has a tree-lined opposite side of street.  Built in 1842 tho, may help.

Comment: Color scheme of the license plates points to Texas, South Dakota, Ohio or Idaho.  Personally by the looks of things it's a town of about 10-20k people at the most.  Can't say I'd call it a city.

Answer (score 17):

There is an answer in the [site that Mark linked](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?s=4840bb5761ce1d0fa36254fb9ad7f1a6&p=118714584#post118714584) in the comments. It is Salem, Massachusetts, and the building is Essex County Juvenile Court.

[Google Street View](https://www.google.nl/maps/@42.5230269,-70.8962956,3a,75y,274.02h,77.16t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1szMPqs475e_ETmcSrpUoWJA!2e0)

Answer (score 4):

The city is Salem in Massachusetts. The building that looks like a greek temple is maybe Registry of Deeds and Probate Court located at [36 Federal street](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.5230119,-70.8965756,3a,75y,275.5h,88.88t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sUwzPA3r1xrHrbNv1U4Cexw!2e0).